# How to put semicolon separated string into an array?

Tags: php, csv, explode

Well I was just wondering how can I put this semicolon separated string into an array

```
one,two,three; four,five,six; if( i < x { "seven,eight"; } if( x < i ) { nine; }
```

The result I need would be

```
[0] => one,two,three
[1] => four,five,six
[2] => if( i < x { "seven,eight"; } if( x < i ) { nine; }
```

I know how to explode those separated values but I'm stuck in this

```
if( i < x { "seven,eight"; } if( x < i ) { nine; }
```

The original data is this

```
bonus2 bAddRace,RC_DemiHuman,80; bonus2 bIgnoreDefRate,RC_DemiHuman,30; if(getrefine()>=6) { bonus2 bAddRace,RC_DemiHuman,40; } if(getrefine()>=9) {  autobonus2 "{ bonus bShortWeaponDamageReturn,20; bonus bMagicDamageReturn,20; }",200,1000,BF_WEAPON,"{ specialeffect2 EF_REFLECTSHIELD; }"; }
```

The code I've tried so far is this

```
function build_item_script_options( $data = array() )
{
    $html = "";
    $bonus_txt = "";
    $bonus_opts = "";
    $bonus_opts_array = array();

    $script = explode( ";", $data['script'] );
    for( $i = 0; $i <= count( $script ) - 1; $i++ )
    {
        if( strtolower( substr( $script[$i], 0, 5 ) ) == 'bonus' )
        {
            $bonus = explode( ',', $script[$i] );
            for( $k = 1; $k <= $bonus[$i] - 1; $k++ )
            {
                array_push( $bonus_opts_array, $bonus[$i][$k] );
            }
            $bonus_txt = $bonus[0];
            $bonus_opts = implode( ',', $bonus_opts_array );
        }
        else
        {
            $bonus_txt = $script[$i];
        }

        $html .= "<option opts=\"" . $bonus_opts . "\" value=\"" . $bonus_txt . "\" selected=selected>" . $bonus_txt . "</option>";
    }

    return $html;
}
```

Comment: You can use a complex chunk or explode or you can use regex. Regex will be easier and faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
$str = 'one,two,three; four,five,six; if( i < x { "seven,eight"; } if( x < i ) { nine; }';
$str = explode("; ", $str, 3);
print_r($str);
```

Example:

> http://codepad.org/fqKMTUcp

** **EDIT** **

You could also try this:

```
$open_brackets = '0';
$string = '';
$str = 'one,two,three; four,five,six; if( i < x { "seven,eight"; } if( x < i ) { nine; }';
$split = str_split($str);
foreach($split as $bracket){
$string .= $bracket;
if($open_brackets == '0' && $bracket == ';'){
$string = substr_replace($string, "*", -1);
}
if($bracket == '{'){
$open_brackets++;
}
if($bracket == '}'){
$open_brackets--;
}
}
$string = explode('* ', $string);
print_r($string);
```

Example:

> http://codepad.org/uO9sGnDz

Comment: What if the string has more than three elements? Or if there are more code snippets between even more "non-code" snippets that are all separated?

Comment: @Flame Trap, Thank you for your second solution, I'll go try this http://codepad.org/uO9sGnDz and randomly check my inputs. I'll get back in this discussion to accept your answer once validated as working.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that by simply exploding with `;` - What you want to do there seems a lot like parsing a languae, for which you'd need an actual language parser that has intelligence, so it can decide wether or not a `;` belongs to the first level or is inside other functions that don't need exploding.

You could e.g. count the amount of brackets you encounter as you move along the string and only explode if the `;` occurss at at time when no brackets are opened.

Some psuedo code:

```
function explode_context_sensitive(string str) {
    int open_brackets = 0, last_semicolon = 0;
    string[] result = new string[];
    for (int idx = 0; idx < strlen(str); idx++) {
        if (str[idx] == ";" && open_brackets == 0) {
            result[] = substr(str, last_semicolon, idx);
            last_semicolon = idx;
        }
        else if (str[idx] == "(")
            ++open_brackets;
        else if (str[idx] == ")")
            --open_brackets;
    }
    return result;
}
```

You'll want to expand such a method to suit your needs, maybe counting different types of brackets or dealing with unsuited brackets...

In short: You're in for a lot of work if you want to do that right. Context-sensitive language parsing is extremely difficult if you don't want to recreate the whole grammar of the language.

Answer (score 0):

use * or some other special character not semicolon, because it may conflict sometimes as php recognize is as a statement breaker.
try this :

```
$value = explode('*',$arr);
```

now you can access your array (arr) values by $value[0],$value[1] etc.
also you have to use at the time of implode this:

```
$arr = implode('*',my,name,is,this);
```

this will produce as my*name*is*this.
you can simply break it by using explode which is on top.
happy coding!

Comment: What if, inside one of the snippets, is a `*`? This will break your exploding again.

Answer (score -1):

```
[2] => ( i < x ) ? "seven,eight":  "nine";
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: OP is talking about splitting the string `"one,two,three; four,five,six; if( i < x { "seven,eight"; } if( x < i ) { nine; }"`. Treat that not as code but as a string. :-)

Comment: @futuregeek, No I was looking for some code to split the semicolon separated string and put it into an array.

Comment: Then regex seems to be your best option, provided you have a known structure for your input string.